# Vue - Best way to loop through multiple custom components with different types of inputs and binding dynamic v-model data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, vue-composition-api

I have a custom component which has 4 different inputs -

CustomNumberInput1
CustomNumberInput2
Checkbox1
Checkbox2

"CustomNumberInput" is another simple custom component which just creates a number input with buttons which will increment/decrement. The value of this input is then emitted to the  "CustomComponent" on change. This is not a child component as it can be used elsewhere.

The main custom component is then looped over many times and written out. I am trying to figure out what is the best way to store the data from these custom components which will eventually be stored in a database.

I am struggling to figure out how to make it so that each custom component is unique as at the moment the `v-model` data is changing for every component.

Eventually this data will be stored in a database and I already have an active Vuex state so it might be best to utilise that.

I am using Nuxt with the composition API.

Comment: imo, if its a single input which is not 100's of lines long like a country select, then just use a normal element, you don't have to abstract simple inputs into components, unless your making your own UI lib, like bootstrap-vue etc, but to use v-model on a component, just put it on it, then use `@input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"` to emit the input, the model is listening on the @input, so just emit it, same with @change etc

Comment: You should probably propagate and store the data in a main parent component. More code will be required here tho, to help you.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone - The input number component has been turned into a component because it has custom events bound to inputs to handle changing the value. Rather than using the built in wheel UI. Its also used in multiple other places not related to this. Hence why its a standalone component.

Comment: @kissu - So inside the custom component I would emit the 4 different inputs data up to the parent component and then have the data bound to a v-model in the parent view? I'll give it a go. Thanks

Comment: If `v-model` is too annoying, split it into regular props/emits.